# Differences between MATLAB and WolframAlpha and AstromMurray (minimun phase)

Tags: matlab, phase, bode

I have the following problem when I graph the phase of my transfer function in matlab I get that it starts at 360 while with wolfram it gives me 0 and if I do the calculation that is in astromurray it gives me that the system also starts at 0, a that this difference is due, what would be the correct diagram. From already thank you very much. Greetings.

$$TF = \frac{(100 - s)^{2}}{(s + 1)^{2}}$$

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are doing in Matlab appears to be wrong.

Matlab has no problem getting the correct result if you code it correctly

```
%% Angle of a transfer function
s = 1i*logspace(-1,3,1000); % s-plane frequency vector
fx = ((100-s).^2)./((s+1).^2); % transfer function
% calculate and unwrap angle and plot it
semilogx(abs(s),unwrap(angle(fx)/pi*180));
grid('on');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Phase in degree');
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the zpk function z=[100 100];
>> p=[-1 -1];
>> sys=zpk(z,p,1);
>> bode(sys)